# Validation for numeric data Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a program in Javascript that separates even and odd numbers, puts them into an array, adds the sum of numbers, and finds the average.

I'm having an issue not allowing zeros not to count. Because its adding to the array, and when the user types in `6+6`, sum is `12`, average is calculating to `4` because of the extra `0` in the array.

Is there anyway to not allow the zeros to count? Here is what I have so far..

```
var evenarray = [];
    var oddarray = [];
    var avgEven = 0;
    var avgOdd = 0;
    var isValid;
    function numberFunction(){

        do  
        {

            var numbers = prompt("Please enter numbers. Enter empty string to exit.");

            if(numbers % 2 == 0)
            {   
                    evenarray.push(numbers);
                    var sumEven = 0;
                        for (var i=0; i < evenarray.length; i++)
                        {
                            sumEven = sumEven + Number(evenarray[i]);
                        }
                    var avgEven = sumEven/evenarray.length;
                    //alert("even");

            }
            if(numbers % 2 !== 0)
            {
                    oddarray.push(numbers);
                    var sumOdd = 0;
                        for (var i=0; i < oddarray.length; i++)
                        {
                            sumOdd = sumOdd + Number(oddarray[i]);
                        }
                    var avgOdd = sumOdd/oddarray.length;
                    //alert("odd");
            }

            //if(isNaN(numbers)){

                //alert("Only numeric data only");
                //}
        }

        while(numbers !== "");
```

Comment: Where is the zero coming from? What does evenarray look like when you're trying to calculate it? Also, you should use `parseInt` instead of `Number` to ensure that the values are numbers, however, you're only allowing numbers to be pushed into the array, so you don't even need that check...

Comment: Can you post an example of input and output and reproduce the issue here http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: To exclude `0`'s being added why dont you create a filter for `0` ex. `if(numbers % 2 == 0 && numbers !== 0)` and `if(numbers % 2 !== 0 && numbers !== 0)`

Comment: Yes, exactly. What I have so far
http://jsfiddle.net/B5aQv/

Comment: its strange to calculate `sum`s and `average`s at every time the loop is running. you should calculate those after terminating the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do nothing when the number is actually `0`:

```
if (numbers == 0)
{
}
else if(numbers % 2 == 0)
{   
  evenarray.push(numbers);
  var sumEven = 0;
  for (var i=0; i < evenarray.length; i++)
  {
    sumEven = sumEven + Number(evenarray[i]);
  }
  var avgEven = sumEven/evenarray.length;
}
else  // only odds remain
{
  oddarray.push(numbers);
  var sumOdd = 0;
  for (var i=0; i < oddarray.length; i++)
  {
    sumOdd = sumOdd + Number(oddarray[i]);
  }
  var avgOdd = sumOdd/oddarray.length;
}
```

Comment: Returning would jump out of the loop, so that's probably a terrible approach. You could `continue` when `numbers == 0`, if that looks better to you. The end result is exactly the same, and I was trying to introduce as few new ideas as possible in the process of showing a working approach.

Comment: Ahh, missed to `do` loop, you're right. Dunno, maybe I'd use `continue` I guess, or just probably take a completely different approach.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I used this approach. Super simple, don't know how it slipped my mind. Still only a few months of programming under my belt.
Is there a better way to exit the loop rather than having an empty string to exit? When I put in an empty string, it considers it a 0 still and comes up with an alert box that I put under:          

if (numbers == 0)
{
alert("zeros or letters not allowed");
}

I realize I can not have the alert to make that work, but any way to ignore the alert when exiting? **sorry not sure how to make the code show up as a block under these comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
if(numbers % 2 == 0 && numbers !=0) ...
if(numbers % 2 != 0 && numbers !=0) ...
```

so that you don't do anything when numbers == 0;

It's a little strange to call your variable **numbers** instead of **number**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply everyone, i'll definitely try it when I get in. and switch my variable to "number", just did it quickly yesterday so still a little sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

your function should be,

```
function numberFunction(){

    do  
    {
        var numbers = prompt("Please enter numbers. Enter empty string to exit.");
        if(numbers !=0 && !isNaN(numbers)) 
            (numbers %2 == 0)? (evenarray.push(parseInt(numbers))) : (oddarray.push(parseInt(numbers)));
    }while(numbers !== "");

    for(var i = 0; i < evenarray.length; i++)
        sumEven += evenarray[i];

    for(var i = 0; i < oddarray.length; i++)
        sumOdd += oddarray[i];

    avgEven = sumEven / evenarray.length;
    avgOdd = sumOdd / oddarray.length;

document.getElementById("even").innerHTML = evenarray.toString();
document.getElementById("sumEvenTotal").innerHTML = sumEven.toString(); //displays sum of even numbers.
document.getElementById("averageOdd").innerHTML = avgOdd; //displays average of odd numbers.
document.getElementById("averageEven").innerHTML = avgEven; //diplays average of even numbers.
document.getElementById("odd").innerHTML = oddarray.toString(); //displays all odd numbers that were entered.
document.getElementById("sumOddTotal").innerHTML = sumOdd.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already have other answers with solutions to your particular issue, I would suggest a different approach. Think of the data you're manipulating: an array. Try to solve the issue only with data, no user input, no DOM manipulation; just data. This helps to separate concerns, and make your code easier to understand.

Since we're working with arrays, we can make use of some of the built-in JavaScript methods that are present in modern browsers, such as `filter` and `reduce`. These methods are in a way, alternatives to `for` loops, with some pre-defined behavior, and a callback function.

Now, let's think of the steps involved in solving your problem.

1. Get numbers from the user. We can represent this data as an array, as you were already doing.
2. We want all odd numbers, their sum and average.
3. We want all even numbers, their sum and average.
4. We display the data to the user.

In this solution I'm assuming you already have an array with the data, and will be focusing on points 2 and 3. Remember, think of data, user interaction shouldn't be mixed with your data logic. Instead of asking the user for a number on each loop, you could ask the user for a list of numbers directly; you avoid multiple prompts this way, and it lets you separate data and interaction nicely. Ideally you'd validate all user input to match your requirements.

```
// Helpers to work with numbers
var odd = function(x) {
  return x % 2 === 0;
};

var even = function(x) {
  return x % 2 !== 0;
};

var add = function(x, y) {
  return x + y;
};

function solve(ns) {
  // Solve the problem
  // with odd or even numbers
  var result = function(fn) {
    var xs = ns.filter(fn); // odd or even
    var sum = xs.reduce(add);
    return {
      numbers: xs,
      sum: sum,
      average: sum / xs.length
    };
  };
  // Return an object
  // with odd and even results
  return {
    odd: result(odd),
    even: result(even)
  };
}

var numbers = [1,2,3,4]; // from user input
var result = solve(numbers);

console.log(result.odd);
//^ {numbers: [2,4], sum: 6, average: 3}

console.log(result.even);
//^ {numbers: [1,2], sum: 4, average: 2}
```